# Flask session not persisting, losing data on page refresh in SPA

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, socket.io

EDIT: I've realized that the else statement actually isn't even being called, but on page refresh, it sets the `logged_in` value to false. The print inside the else statement never prints. How is it setting to false without me doing it?

I have a Single Page React Application being served by Flask, all on the same server. I am using `socket.io-client` to communicate between the backend and frontend.

After logging in, the frontend loads up the user data just fine. If I refresh the page, I am logged out and sent back in to the login page. Why is the session not persisting?

The Flask session cookie exists in Chrome. The session cookie id matches the session cookie in the browser even after refreshing and being logged out, but the backend returns that the user is not logged in.

It seems like the session cookie is losing its data on refresh.

Here is a snippet of the react code:

```
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.3:5000";
const SocketContext = createContext(null);
const socket = io();

export function useIsLoggedIn() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [response, setResponse] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('join', setResponse);
  }, []);

  if (response.success) {
    console.log("routing to dashboard...");
    navigate("/app/dashboard");
  }

  return response;
}

export function useLogIn() {
  const sendMessage = (channel, message) => {
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  };

  return { sendMessage };
}
```

Here is a snippet of the backend python code:

```
@socketio.on('join')
def on_connect(data):
    try:
        if 'logged_in' in session and session['logged_in']:
            print('logged_in')
            user_content = content.get_content(user=session['username'])
            error = None
            join_room(session['company'])
            emit('sign_in', {'content': user_content, 'error': error, 'success': True}, room=session['company'])
        else:
            print('not_logged_in')
            error = 'Invalid login credentials'
            emit('sign_in', {'content': CONTENT, 'error': error, 'success': False})
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        # print(e)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    print('path', path)
    try:
        print('session logged_in', session['logged_in'])
    except Exception as e:
        print('failed not logged_in', e)
    if 'logged_in' not in session:
        print('set logged_in to False')
        session['logged_in'] = False
        session.permanent = True
    resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
    return resp
```

I have been trying to figure out for weeks why the session is resetting and logging the user out on refresh. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Flask, you should try to handle the login status with Flask libraries, in this case, flask_login.

I'm not giving all the details here, but I believe that you need at least the following to get it working:

On your app definition file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager


login_manager = LoginManager()


def create_app():
    """App factory."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():

        from my_app.views.view_users import view_users
        from my_app.views.main_view import main_view
        app.register_blueprint(view_users)
        app.register_blueprint(main_view)

        # Login manager config
        login_manager.login_view = 'view_users.login'
```

Next, you will need to create the view_users.py. This file should contain the login_user from the flask_login package.

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, redirect, url_for
from flask_login import login_user

view_users = Blueprint('view_users', __name__)


@view_users.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """Login the user."""

    if password_matches(pass_db, passw):  # you need to check the provided password - you will need a form and a html for it
        login_user(user)

        next = url_for('main_view.landing')
        return redirect(next)
```

Of course, you still need to define a function for @login_manager.user_loader and the User class, inherited from flask_login.UserMixin. Please check the doc for that.

Finally, on your view/route/endpoint definition files, decorate every route definition with @login_required:

```
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask import render_template, Blueprint

main_view = Blueprint('main_view', __name__)


@main_view.route('/landing')
@login_required
def landing():
    """Landing page after user login."""
    data = ['my data']
    user_details = current_user  # if you need any - this will come from your user_loader function
    return render_template(
            'landing.html',
            data=data
        )


@main_view.route('/a_end_point')
@login_required
def a_end_point():
    """Landing page after user login."""
    user_details = current_user  # if you need any - this will come from your user_loader function
    data = ['my data']
    return render_template(
            'a_end_point.html',
            data=data
        )
```

Good luck!

Comment: I ended up getting rid of socket.io on both sides and just doing fetch requests on front end combined with app.routes on backend. login staying consistent now. and using context provider instead of custom hooks to handle the data without prop drilling